# Caml Query for exclude those ListItems from a ListItemCollection whose LookUp columns contains text “Full Access”

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, caml-query

I am facing some problem with SharePoint 2013 CAML Query. I have a list and there is a look up column on it. There are some values on the lookup column.For example, I have `Full Access` and `Limited Access` values in look up column. Now I want to get all the `ListItems` whose look up column does not contains "Full Access".

I wrote this query:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="DocumentTypeCal" />
        <Value Type="Text">Databases</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name="Sub_x0020_Categories" />
        <Value Type="Lookup">Limited Access</Value>
      </Contains>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

I have search a bit on Google but I did not find any or any tag that could solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
<Query>
   <Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="DocumentTypeCal" />
        <Value Type="Text">Databases</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Neq>
        <FieldRef Name="Sub_x0020_Categories" />
        <Value Type="Lookup">Full Access</Value>
      </Neq>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

You can also query on the ID of `Full Access` as below

```
<Query>
   <Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="DocumentTypeCal" />
        <Value Type="Text">Databases</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Neq>
        <FieldRef Name="Sub_x0020_Categories" LookupId="TRUE"/>
        <Value Type="Text">1</Value>
      </Neq>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but you are comparing Sub_x0020_Categories value with **Full Access**. I wanted to exclude all the ListItem that contains **Full Access**.
Its not string comparison , Its like String's Contains method. Hope you understand.